# Can table name be used as alias?

Tags: mysql, sql

What would anyone think of this query ?

```
SELECT * FROM ta LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT * FROM tb WHERE tb.end > 10000) AS tb 
ON ta.id = tb.id
```

Is it ok to use table name ("tb") as alias or are there some invisible consequences ?

Reason: I have static methods to map ResultSet to object which use table name prefix. Would be nice to leave these methods alone.

Comment: It is fine to  use. But does `SELECT * FROM tb WHERE tb.end > 10000 ` returns a single column ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use any alias, as long as the alias doesn't conflict with other aliases (tables without alias are give an alias with their name). This applies to a single query scope. In your query you have 2 scopes: one for the outer query and one for the inner query, thus you should not have a conflict even the same alias appears in both scopes.

Comment: But table names themselves are unique, at least in the same schema. I wonder why table names are not commonly used as alias, or are they ?

Comment: Usually the table name is used as alias (if no alias is declared then the alias will be in fact the table name). However there are cases when using the  table name is not possible, for example if you have a recursive relation, like `SELECT parent.id,parent.name FROM person pers LEFT JOIN person parent ON pers.parent_id=parent.id`

Answer (score 1):

Your query looks fine but why don't you use a simple `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT ta.*
FROM ta
LEFT JOIN tb ON ta.id = tb.id
WHERE tb.end > 10000
```

Comment: my query above was not complete

Answer (score 0):

**Yes** it is perfectly fine to use the alias name as the table name.