# Write a query that returns students with the largest amount of the best marks in each subject

Tags: sql

There is a table(named Students) containing columns:

```
Name, Subject, Mark
```

It is required to return the name and the Subject of the best students.
Student is considered best in the subject if he/her has the largest amount of the best marks.

So, if there are entries in the table:

```
('John', 'Math', 10),
('John', 'Math', 10),
('John', 'Math', 11),
('Mia', 'Math', 10),
('Mia', 'Math', 11);
('Bob', 'Science', 12),
('Bob', 'Science', 11),
('Ross', 'Science', 11),
('Ross', 'Science', 12),
('Ross', 'Science', 12)
```

The query should return

```
John Math
Ross Science
```

Because John has two tens and one eleven. Mia has one ten less.

I understand that I need to group entries by Subject, Name and Mark and count the amount of same marks. I tried the following query:

```
SELECT NAME, SUBJECT, MARK, COUNT(*) AS COUNT
FROM STUDENTS
GROUP BY SUBJECT, NAME, MARK
```

It returns:

```
John    Math    10  2
John    Math    11  1
Mia Math    10  1
Mia Math    11  1
Bob Science 12  1
Bob Science 11  1
Ross    Science 11  1
Ross    Science 12  2
```

I have an idea that I need to discard the entries where students have the same amount of particular marks. Here they are Mia and John's elevens. They are of the same amount. So table will look like this:

```
John    Math    10  2
Mia     Math    10  1
Bob     Science 12  1
Ross    Science 12  2
```

And now I have to pick the student with larger amount of marks. But the problem is I have no idea how to do this.

I **do not** ask for the full solution. I particularly ask for help regarding my idea, whether it is reasonable, and, if not, to suggest an alternative

Comment: What's the expected result if top students have matching scores?

Comment: @lummers it is allowed to return either of students or all of them

Comment: I understand your scenario, however why do you need to discard the same amount entries? Maybe you can only sum the marks by student and subjects in your original table.. so you will have:

>     John    Math    31
>     Mia     Math    21

So, Jhon with 31 points is the best in this case, avoiding to discard entries.

Comment: Are you just needing the top person?  You can just sum the marks and LIMIT 1 ..   `SELECT NAME, SUBJECT, MARK, COUNT(*) AS COUNT SUM(MARK) AS MARK FROM STUDENTS ... `

Comment: @JotaPardo because if John has 31 mark with value 1 the query will return John's name while the right result is Mia, because she has higher mark (11)

Comment: @Zak Nope, it is completely possible to have entries of students in other subject, for example, science. Therefore, query should return two best students - one in Math and the other one - in Science

Comment: Since all your Sample data says Math (Not Science) .. I suggest you edit your question with a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Limiting your query can be done by only returning the stuff where the minimal count is unequal to the maximal count, see: https://dbfiddle.uk/jsGAVaaE

Comment: What if you add ('Bob', 'Science', 12) what would be the expected result?

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Comment: @PsychoWit you cannot, as you've uploaded it under the CC BY-SA 4.0 license, as I mentioned above. You can try to [contact](https://stackoverflow.co/company/contact) Stack Exchange, the company behind SO, directly to help in this regard. Then again, this data already looks like dummy data, so what is the problem with sharing this?

Comment: That isn't Stack Overflow's problem either, given you've knowingly and willingly distributed your question to the public under the CC BY-SA license. You'll need to contact SE, because this is now a legal issue.

Comment: This is not a private lesson over a whiteboard. You have a question, you post it, you (hopefully) get answered. You **DO NOT** modify your question after you already got your answer(s). If you wish to ask something else, open a new post for it.

Answer (score 1):

I counted the top marks per `name` and `subject` and then numbered by `max(mark) desc` and then `count desc` to get only the result with the most counts.

```
select name 
      ,subject 
  
from   (
       select name
             ,subject
             ,rank() over(partition by subject order by max(mark) desc, count(*) desc) as rnk
       from   t
       group by name, subject
       ) t
where  rnk = 1
```

| name | subject |
| --- | --- |
| John | Math |
| Ross | Science |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qHEEfPo4)

Comment: How does "from t" works if t is only declared outside of the expression

Comment: @PsychoWit The inner query is a table so I named it. I had to do it to use `row_number` in the `where`. t is also how I named my original table that has the info you provided in it.You can see it in the fiddle.

Comment: @DannySlor: Using an alias for a table name which happens to be the same as an existing table is .... (not good?)

Comment: Okay, gotcha. Will read about row_number. Thank you for the solution.

Comment: @Luuk The opposite. The table didn't change in essence so I want to show that it's still the same material. Once you start joining many tables it makes more sense to keep it the same as much as possible.

Comment: @DannySlor: OK, i see, (https://stackoverflow.com/a/29506378/724039), but I am still against it because readability of you query is not improving (But that's just my opinion )`

Comment: What if you add ('Bob', 'Science', 12)? I got 

John Math
Bob Science...

but Ross has twice 12 mark... should be Ross not Bob in your query

Comment: @PsychoWit If you use this solution, beware that some of the functions that you haven't learned yet may come into play, particularly `partition by` (Which is how I was hinting at in the other comment).  If this is homework, this answer may be more advanced than your current lesson.

Comment: @JotaPardo The question is what he wants. What if someone has one 12 and one 9, but someone else has three 11s? I did change `row_number` to `rank` though and now it makes more sense.

Comment: The problem right now is if I have:
('John', 'Math', 10),
('John', 'Math', 10),
('John', 'Math', 11),
('Mia', 'Math', 10),
('Mia', 'Math', 11),
('Bob', 'Science', 12),
('Bob', 'Science', 12),
('Ross', 'Science', 12),
('Ross', 'Science', 14);

The result is:
John Math
Bob Science
Ross Science

Ross has a 14 and he is the only best in Science

Comment: @DannySlor I modified row_number() over(partition by subject order by count(*) desc, sum(mark) desc) and it worked with the scenario if you add ('Bob', 'Science', 12)

Comment: @Zak it is a riddle, given to me by my mentor to check how fast I surrender I guess. He said that it is a senior question, so....

Comment: @JotaPardo it worked with the scenario you talk about, but that's not what he's asking and if you see in his comments you will see that he's not asking for that.

Comment: @DannySlor with the new scenario in the comments from the author is working as he is expecting

Comment: @JotaPardo what you added did not work:
('Bob', 'Science', 12),
('Bob', 'Science', 12),
('Ross', 'Science', 14);

Result:
John Math
Bob Science

Ross has 14 and he should be best in science

Comment: @PsychoWit try with row_number() over(partition by subject order by count(*) desc, sum(mark) desc) as rn in the same solution from DannySlor.. It worked as you are expecting

Comment: @PsychoWit fixed it. now it first gives preference to the highest mark and then to the number of marks.

Comment: @JotaPardo that won't work because it doesn't order by highest mark first. look at my updated answer. Also, you want to use `rank` in case two students get the same results.

Comment: @DannySlor max(mark) does not work if you have: ('Bob', 'Science', 12),
('Bob', 'Science', 11),
('Bob', 'Science', 11),
('Ross', 'Science', 50),
('Ross', 'Science', 50);

It shows Ross Science, but it would be Bob Science

Comment: @JotaPardo it shouldn't, it should  be ('Ross', 'Science') in that case. He just said it in the comment above.

Comment: @PsychoWit what if you have:  if you have: ('Bob', 'Science', 12), ('Bob', 'Science', 11), ('Bob', 'Science', 11), ('Ross', 'Science', 50), ('Ross', 'Science', 50); What would be the result?

Comment: @JotaPardo Ross has larger grade and therefore he is better

Comment: So @DannySlor is right your answer. Because it is not based on the number of marks first, but it is base in the larger grade first.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like homework so I will answer in the most general terms for you to investigate to completion.

Investigate the SQL language looking for topics dealing with:

1. aggregating data using different functions
2. ordering results
3. limiting the number of results returned

You will most likely have to use different functions and group by syntax in the end.

Comment: Edited the post. Did not express the task entirely correctly

Comment: There are more than one subject. Therefore I do not understand how limiting is helpful for the task. I have the knowledge of the previous two bullet points. Maybe the third I did not understand correctly

Comment: @PsychoWit -- You will limit the result set based on the number of subjects.

Comment: Can I have a hint in the direction of which functions I should look. Knowing the topic of aggregating data does not help to solve problems. Experience and practice do.